# ksvm not recognizing predicted value

Tags: r

I am creating a predictive model for one of my classes in library(ksvm), but I keep getting the error: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'y' not found."

```
model <- ksvm(y ~ ., data = Train)
```

I am transcribing what the instructor wrote for the code verbatim (and it worked for him in the demo), but I keep getting this error. I'm told the dot is to select everything, but RStudio doesn't seem to recognize it when I do it? Is there another way to do this? My best guess is that maybe the demo is dated and the way to indicate everything for the predicted value has changed?

(Here is the code I've used up to this spot:

```
> AirQuality <- na.omit(airquality)
> rowNum <- nrow(AirQuality)
> cutPoint <- floor(rowNum/3*2)
> rand <- sample(1:rowNum)
> head(rand)
[1]  95  68 101   9  30 106
> Train <- AirQuality[rand[1:cutPoint],]
> Test <- AirQuality[rand[(cutPoint+1:rowNum)],]
> library(kernlab)
> model <- ksvm(y ~ ., data=Train)
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'y' not found
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data? or at least the output of `summary(Train)`?

Comment: It's using the airquality dataset; I added what I had up until that error to my original post. 
I've had the same issues with some of the functions in ggplot. "color=" and "map=" no longer work for me. I had no issues using either back in April, but then they suddenly just weren't recognized anymore.

Comment: `ksvm` is used for classification. You need to specify a predictor variable that is actually in your data. Your data does not have `y` as a variable